# How to find an address of a C global variable at compile time

Tags: c, compilation, linker

I'm doing some code generation. Is it possible to find the future address of a global C variable at compile time?

Suppose there is a global variable in a C file:

```
const char[] bytecode = "generated bytecode goes here";
```

After that, I need to add code pointing to `bytecode` at compile time:

```
const char* ptrInsideBytecode = 0x1234 + offset; 
// 0x1234 should be the address of bytecode
```

It is not an option to just refer to bytecode field, the pointer must be fixed.

I know that myVar will be at some fixed position after compilation and linking, so this should be possible. How do I find the exact address of `bytecode` before compiling?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization

Comment: Put a random address, compile, disassemble and get the reference(s), change the random address with the real one in the binary with an hex editor. And disable ASLR

Comment: This sounds weird, what are you trying to achive ?

Comment: If you are working on something embedded, see if you can fixate that variable on a fixed address by (1) directly specifying the address in some attribute. (2) putting it as only variable in a section that is put on a fixed adress using the linker response file.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a way to do this, because the compiler must perform the summation in order to know what the value is, however the address won't be known until the linker has run.

Depending on your platform, you may be able to place your bytecode at a fixed location in memory by using a linker script.  This is only likely to work if you're on a microcontroller that doesn't have an operating system.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't have an address at compile time; to see why, you could compile it on a different machine than the one (or more!) that it gets executed on.

Answer (score 0):

```
const char bytecode[] = "generated bytecode goes here";

// After that, I need to add code pointing to bytecode at compile time:
#define offset 6

const char *ptrInsideBytecode = bytecode + offset;

// the address you want >>>-----^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: I'm actually writing the value to a constant (in Flash EPROM...), so unless above is somehow computed at compile time, it wouldn't work.

Comment: On platforms with a (dynamic) loader (such as the PC) the above code will probably emit a fixup. For a freestanding platform the (static) loader *should* know the address of the array, and fix the reference to it up statically, IMHO.